# Excel | autostart macro on cell value change | cause crash

Tags: vba, excel

first of all I'm not a VBA programmer but typically an end-user who uses snippets of code that I gather in forums like this in his spreadsheets, trying to understand what the code does. Code for which I thank you all!

**My objective:**
I have a spreadsheet that is basically an input-form for users.
Based on their input and selections via dropdown my intention is to guide them through the form by hiding & unhiding rows with input fields, presenting the users with the relevant questions.

On each row I have created an IF-formula that creates a 1 or 0 based on previous provided input
1 -> unhide the row , 0 -> hide the row.

So I'm looking for a macro that runs with every sheet calculation and hides or unhides the next rows as needed.

These formulas are in range `I3:I70` on top of that I created a summary field in `I2`  `=sum(I3:I70)` so i thought I can either check changes in the range `I3:I70` or changes on cell `I2` to trigger the macro.  [Neither solution fixed my problem]

I've tried several code examples discribed on the forums and I've tested the macros that checks for change in the range or the cell individually. 
As long as I call a test macro with a `MsgBox` it works fine.
Also the macro that hides or unhides runs fine when I call it manually.

**My problem:**
When I let the 'auto'-macro call the 'hide'-macro, **Excel simply crashes**; no warnings, nothing --> just crash.

**My code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim Xrg As Range
    Set Xrg = Range("H3:H70")
    If Not Intersect(Xrg, Range("H3:H70")) Is Nothing Then
    Macro1
    End If
End Sub

Sub Sample()
MsgBox "Yes"
End Sub

Sub Macro1()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("H3:H70")
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If cell.Value = 0 Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
            If cell.Value = 1 Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks for any suggestions and tips in advance.

JeWe

Comment: Why don't you use the macro to add/remove shapes to cover the workbook instead of hiding rows? Would be considerably easier.

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera For easier readability, it seems that hiding a row would be better

Comment: Can you try adding an error handler in there? This might be able to catch the error and output a message before the crash occurs. Also, check to see if your Error Trapping is set to *Break on Unhandled Errors*

Answer (score 1):

Never give up searching :-) I gave it a last search and found some code on the microsfof dot com site that seems to work.
Don't ask me the details but this seems to do what i'm looking for

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Range("H3:H70")
   If c.Value = 0 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf c.Value = 1 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It's late on my end of the world, going to sleep. Will update tomorrow.
Txs JeWe